# Case Sharing Rule Not Working

Tags: case, sharing, sharing-rule, criteria-based-sharing

I am creating a case by associating it with contact.

- OWD of Case: Private
- OWD of Account: Private
- OWD of Contact: Controlled by parent

Case assignment will change the owner to a queue on case creation.

Sharing rule created:

- On Account: Criteria based sharing rule : All internal users access provided (CASE ACCESS PRIVATE ON ACCOUNT SHARING RULE)
- On Case: Criteria based sharing rule: All internal users access
  provided

Issue: When I am creating a case, I am getting insufficient access to cross reference id.

I want to retain the access of the creator of the case. I saw few other stack exchange resolved answers and found people are suggesting to add creator on the case team. But that I shouldn't be doing because i have a sharing rule to provide access to case for all internal users.

Just fyi: If i add creator to the queue itself which will get assigned via assignment rule, then access is retained because creator is present as owner within queue --- But i dont want to put creator within queue.

Update:

While analysis this issue a bite more, I found out that the assignment rule is sending out an email to the queue members. The email template is a visualforce email template. If I changed it to basic text email template, it works. I even remove code from VF template and template I provided above in question. Still it did not work...but when i used text email template it works

VF template:

<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Case # {!relatedTo.Casenumber} has been assigned to you " relatedToType="Case">

<messaging:htmlEmailBody >

test

</messaging:htmlEmailBody>
</messaging:emailTemplate>

Now, if i remove: the only merge field present in vf template, it started to work !

Comment: Is the case creator an internal user that is included in your Case sharing rule? If so, this might be a bug or there's something else going on. Open a case with SF support. Somewhat related issue that is (allegedly) a bug: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9062I000000XqMXQA0

Comment: Yes case creator is an internal user that is included in case sharing rule. While analysis this issue just now I found out that the assignment rule is sending out an email to the queue members. The email template is a visualforce email template. If I changed it to basic text email template, it works. I even remove code from VF template and template I provided above in question. Still it did not work...but when i used text email template it works.

Comment: Opening a support case sounds like a good idea.